# Downloading images from server

Tags: iphone, ios, image, download

I am creating the app for my client, it is a wallpaper app. Images will be downloaded from his server. Server isn't setup yet and his looking for easy way to add new images.

What would be the best way to download images from server?
Can you send me a link to some tutorial? I haven't done this before and I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

In `Synchronous` manner you can do it simply using:

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ezwebrus.com/wallpapers/cartoons/donald_and_daisy.jpg"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

But I won't recommend the above code. Because if your connection is too slow it can make your application unresponsive.

Here are some links:

1. [Download and create an image from a url](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/download-and-create-an-image-from-a-url.html)
2. [Download an Image and Save it as PNG or JPEG in iPhone SDK](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/)
3. For Asynchronous image loading [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: SDWebImage looks interesting, I will check it out later.
Regarding server, would the best way be the client sends me JSON file which contains all URLs od wallpapers that are downloaded to app? Or maybe XML, SQL database? What is the best approach to download all images from his server?

Comment: All are best options. According to your requirement choose any of them. If you want to work with the response from server JSON or XML will be the best option